# Ordering list of integers by the count of each element in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to order the elements of a list of integers by how many times the integer appears in the list.

So the first element of the result list should be the most common element in the original list, the second is the second most common, and so on. Each integer should only be included once in the result list, not as many times as the original list contains it. Secondary order is not important.

For example, for `1,2,3,2,1,6,2`, I would like to get `2,1,3,6` (`2` appears thrice, `1` appears twice, `3` and `6` both appear only once).

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Also, what would you want the output to look like?

Comment: In the case of duplicate frequency what should be your secondary order? Numerical value asc/desc?

Comment: output 2,1,3,6. The secondory order isn't important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

- Group by each item
- Order by descending based on group count
- select **unique** item based on group key

Like:

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 6, 2 };
var query = list.GroupBy(item => item)
                .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
                .Select(grp => grp.Key);


foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

EDIT:

If you don't want unique item, but all the items based on their occurrence then use:

```
var query = list.GroupBy(item => item)
                .OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count())
                .SelectMany(grp => grp);
```

`SelectMany` will flatten the list and give you an output like:

```
2
2
2
1
1
3
6
```

Comment: My understanding is that OP wants to order things without eliminating duplicates. In other words, the number of items returned from the query needs to be equal to the number of items going in, but using the specific order that OP wants.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight, thanks for clearing that, I have added code for that as well in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GroupBy` and `OrderBy`:

```
        var list = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 6, 2 };
        list.GroupBy(x => x).OrderBy(x => x.Count()).Select(x => x.Key);
```